# Confirmation for the expression of 'Your feet don't step on the land'

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, grammaticality-in-context

Does this expression make sense in English?

"These days my feet don't step on the land"

This is a literal translation from the Hindi language.  If I say it in reference to myself, it means I'm happily proud to have become something, but I don't know whether or not it means the same in English. If someone uses the same expression in reference to others, it indicates envy of the other's successes.

Comment: I think you can ask this question in a better way. You can provide an explicit context and request for a matching idiom.

Comment: _My feet don't step on the land_  would be puzzling to most English speakers. It would not be perceived as expressing pride in an accomplishment.

Comment: I think that this question has been asked before.

Comment: "Gonna" is a very informal verb form. We use it in casual conversation or text messaging, but never in other settings—such as an ELL question!

Comment: Mick Sharp@ where have you seen this or read? Ive just translated it by myself from a hindi song and also heard that expression from many hindi native speakers

Comment: @Arman I'm sure that I've seen it on this site but I can't find it. Maybe the questioner deleted it for some reason. I'll let you know if I find it.

Answer (score 4):

A possible equivalent idioms in English which have to do with *floating* might be

> [floating on air](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-walking-floating-on-air)
>   [over the moon](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=over+the+moon+meaning&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

which mean to be very happy about *something*, or

> [feet don't touch the ground](http://www.metrolyrics.com/feet-dont-touch-the-ground-lyrics-larue-stoney.html)
>   [feet won't touch the ground](https://www.reddit.com/r/Coldplay/comments/1voyhi/what_is_with_coldplay_and_feet_not_touching_the/)

which may mean to be levitated in an enlightened state of mind, possibly happiness, possibly unburdened.

None of the phrases indicate envy directly, envy would need to be expressed either in intonation or additional context.

Another phrase, without allusion to *floating* is

> [bragging rights](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bragging%20rights)

which are usually attained by an extraordinary feat of accomplishment

> Michael Phelps has *bragging rights* for the most number of Olympic medals.

Comment: Neither of these specify pride in an accomplishment. They are merely general expressions of elation, of which there are scores.

Answer (score 3):

There is the expression [*walk on air*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/walk-on-air), which means to feel elated, but there is no connotation of envy when used in reference to another person.

There is also the expression "my feet didn't touch the floor", but this means that you were so busy that you didn't have time to do anything else. When used in reference to another person, it indicates sympathy.

This means that a literal translation of the Hindi saying could be confusing. I wonder how the translation engines cope with it?